# VSCode set width for code formatting of arrays etc

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, format, dartfmt

If my array goes over a certain length:

```
const List hts = [200, 195, 190, 185, 180, 175, 170, 165, 160, 155, 150, 145];
```

VSCode formats it like this:

```
const List hts = [
  200,
  195,
  190,
  185,
  180,
  175,
  170,
  165,
  160,
  155,
  150,
  145,
  140
];
```

I'd rather it didn't since it makes a short array take up half the page. How can I change this?

Also I get even weirder formatting like this which means if I comment out a line it only comments out half the line:

This:

```
   Text('RESULTS', style: kMainText),
   Text('Additional', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: kSmallText),
```

Gets formatted as this:

```
   Text('RESULTS', style: kMainText),
   Text('Additional',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: kSmallText),
```

The second line is one line but I have to comment it out as two lines. It seems like there's some kind of 'length' setting somewhere that I could alter to avoid this. How can I edit all this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dart VS Code extension uses [dart_style](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_style) for formatting, which ships in the Dart SDK.

There is a setting called "maximum line length" which can be configured in your VS Code settings in the Dart section which will allow lines to be longer before they wrap (though note that this applies to all lines, not just lists).

There's an issue requesting an alternative (more customisable) formatter in VS Code here:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/914

Please add a  to the issue if it's something you'd like to see.

Comment: So in the VSCode settings there is `Dart: Line Length` which should do exactly what I want but there is an issue in that it does not affect Lists? Any idea when that will be fixed? I wouldn't need any more than that so the issue link you point to would be unnecessary. But this line length List bug being fixed would be great.

Comment: Actually it does seem to affect lists? I modified the `Dart: Line Length` from 80 to 100 and my above List no longer formats in that huge space occupying way.

Comment: > there is an issue in that it does not affect Lists? Any idea when that will be fixed

My understanding from the comment I linked was that it was by design. I tried making it really large and it did not seem to affect my list formatting - I'm glad it seems to work for you though! :-)

Comment: Yeah I think it works as intended, the longer you make the line length, the longer the line will need to be before it starts moving it all down the page - Lists included.

Comment: If you edit your answer I can select it, otherwise it may mislead people into thinking it doesn't work with lists.

Answer (score 1):

The dart formatter will preserve line breaks in an list if there's a comment line at the head of this list.

For example, to format a very long list in Dart:

```dart
[
  // yeah
  a,b,c,
  d,e,f,
];
```

See the test case ([link](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/blob/f17c23e0eea9a870601c19d904e2a9c1a7c81470/test/splitting/lists.stmt#L110)) from official dart style repository (https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style)

Comment: Oh really? That's kind of odd. What's the reason for that then?

Comment: Ask the collaborators, I just someone who discover it searching the web and confirmed it works.